# Get an item from a javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have the following json file : api.json with the following json:

```
[
  {
    "stop_ids": 70021,
    "stop_name": "22ND ST STATION",
    "stop_lat": 37.757692,
    "stop_lon": -122.392318,
    "trip_id": 101,
    "departure_time": "08:20:00",
    "arrival_time": "09:13:00",
    "arrival_name": "ATHERTON STATION",
    "train_name": ["sbs local", "Shuttle Mak", "beast tar"],
    "zone_id": 3329
  },
  {
    "stop_ids": 70022,
    "stop_name": "ATHERTON STATION",
    "stop_lat": 37.464458,
    "stop_lon": -122.198152,
    "trip_id": 102,
    "departure_time": "07:37:00",
    "arrival_time": "08:30:00",
    "arrival_name": "22ND ST STATION",
    "train_name": ["sbs local", "Shuttle Mak", "beast tar"],
    "zone_id": 3329
  },
  {
    "stop_ids": 70023,
    "stop_name": "BAYSHORE STATION",
    "stop_lat": 37.711202,
    "stop_lon": -122.401366,
    "trip_id": 103,
    "departure_time": "12:31:00",
    "arrival_time": "12:41:00",
    "arrival_name": "SAN FRANCISCO",
    "train_name": ["sbs local", "Shuttle Mak", "beast tar"],
    "zone_id": 3329
  },
  {
    "stop_ids": 70024,
    "stop_name": "SAN FRANCISCO",
    "stop_lat": 37.776541,
    "stop_lon": -122.395406,
    "trip_id": 104,
    "departure_time": "12:00:00",
    "arrival_time": "01:06:00",
    "arrival_name": "SAN ANTONIO",
    "train_name": ["sbs local", "Shuttle Mak", "beast tar"],
    "zone_id": 3329
  }
  ]
```

What I want to do is get an item from the object given the stop_name and arrival_name.

Let say:

```
var fromStop = "SAN FRANCISCO";
var toStop = "SAN ANTONIO";
```

How can I get the item with the above info from the object using pure javascript so I can be able to access the item index values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `Array#filter`

```
input.filter(function(item) {
  return item.stop_name === fromStop && item.arrival_name === toStop;
});
```

```js
var input = [{
  "stop_ids": 70021,
  "stop_name": "22ND ST STATION",
  "stop_lat": 37.757692,
  "stop_lon": -122.392318,
  "trip_id": 101,
  "departure_time": "08:20:00",
  "arrival_time": "09:13:00",
  "arrival_name": "ATHERTON STATION",
  "train_name": ["sbs local", "Shuttle Mak", "beast tar"],
  "zone_id": 3329
}, {
  "stop_ids": 70022,
  "stop_name": "ATHERTON STATION",
  "stop_lat": 37.464458,
  "stop_lon": -122.198152,
  "trip_id": 102,
  "departure_time": "07:37:00",
  "arrival_time": "08:30:00",
  "arrival_name": "22ND ST STATION",
  "train_name": ["sbs local", "Shuttle Mak", "beast tar"],
  "zone_id": 3329
}, {
  "stop_ids": 70023,
  "stop_name": "BAYSHORE STATION",
  "stop_lat": 37.711202,
  "stop_lon": -122.401366,
  "trip_id": 103,
  "departure_time": "12:31:00",
  "arrival_time": "12:41:00",
  "arrival_name": "SAN FRANCISCO",
  "train_name": ["sbs local", "Shuttle Mak", "beast tar"],
  "zone_id": 3329
}, {
  "stop_ids": 70024,
  "stop_name": "SAN FRANCISCO",
  "stop_lat": 37.776541,
  "stop_lon": -122.395406,
  "trip_id": 104,
  "departure_time": "12:00:00",
  "arrival_time": "01:06:00",
  "arrival_name": "SAN ANTONIO",
  "train_name": ["sbs local", "Shuttle Mak", "beast tar"],
  "zone_id": 3329
}];
var fromStop = "SAN FRANCISCO";
var toStop = "SAN ANTONIO";
var filtered = input.filter(function(item) {
  return item.stop_name === fromStop && item.arrival_name === toStop;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Let the record show that I answered first using nothing but my thumbs :-p.

Comment: @Rayon I have the json in a different folder and my javascript in a different folder. How can I do a reference so I get the json to a javascript array(input)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the array's find method.

```
var toStop = "Footopia",
       fromStop = "Barsville";
api.json.find(function(item) {return item.stop_name == fromStop && item.arrival_name == toStop;});
```

P.S.: I'm answering from the SO iPhone app so please forgive any formatting mistakes.

Comment: That's okay except that how do I reference the json file to my javascript file so I don't get the  'api is not defined'?

Comment: Ahh, well now you're asking a completely different question. I believe you can pull in the data from a file using a command similar to the $.ajax command in jQuery, but I don't know it off the top of my head. If I have time later, I'll find the answer and revisit this question.

Answer (score 0):

jsonOb is the parsed json object

```
var fromStop = "SAN FRANCISCO";
  var toStop = "SAN ANTONIO";
  var result = {};
  for(i=0;i<jsonOb.length;i++)
  {
        if(fromStop == jsonOb[i].stop_name && toStop == jsonOb[i].arrival_name)
        {
            result = jsonOb[i];
            break;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the objects and find the matche

```
  var result;
  var fromStop = "SAN FRANCISCO";
  var toStop = "SAN ANTONIO";
  for (var i=0 ; i < obj.length ; i++){

      if (obj[i]['stop_name'] == fromStop && obj[i]['arrival_name'] == toStop ) {
          result = "The index is : "+i;
          break;
      }
  }
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
function getObjectFromList(fromStop, toStop, fromStopValue, toStopValue,list){
    return list.filter(function (item) {
        return ((item[fromStop] === fromStopValue) && (item[toStop] === toStopValue));
    });
};

var a = getObjectFromList("stop_name", "arrival_name", "SAN FRANCISCO", "SAN ANTONIO", obj);

console.log(a);
```

**Output :**

[image]

**Fiddle demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/zvdq4vLk/

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. The `reduce` one gets you the indices of all matching objects and the `findIndex` method gets you the first matching object's index.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "stop_ids": 70021,
    "stop_name": "22ND ST STATION",
    "stop_lat": 37.757692,
    "stop_lon": -122.392318,
    "trip_id": 101,
    "departure_time": "08:20:00",
    "arrival_time": "09:13:00",
    "arrival_name": "ATHERTON STATION",
    "train_name": ["sbs local", "Shuttle Mak", "beast tar"],
    "zone_id": 3329
  },
  {
    "stop_ids": 70022,
    "stop_name": "ATHERTON STATION",
    "stop_lat": 37.464458,
    "stop_lon": -122.198152,
    "trip_id": 102,
    "departure_time": "07:37:00",
    "arrival_time": "08:30:00",
    "arrival_name": "22ND ST STATION",
    "train_name": ["sbs local", "Shuttle Mak", "beast tar"],
    "zone_id": 3329
  },
  {
    "stop_ids": 70023,
    "stop_name": "BAYSHORE STATION",
    "stop_lat": 37.711202,
    "stop_lon": -122.401366,
    "trip_id": 103,
    "departure_time": "12:31:00",
    "arrival_time": "12:41:00",
    "arrival_name": "SAN FRANCISCO",
    "train_name": ["sbs local", "Shuttle Mak", "beast tar"],
    "zone_id": 3329
  },
  {
    "stop_ids": 70024,
    "stop_name": "SAN FRANCISCO",
    "stop_lat": 37.776541,
    "stop_lon": -122.395406,
    "trip_id": 104,
    "departure_time": "12:00:00",
    "arrival_time": "01:06:00",
    "arrival_name": "SAN ANTONIO",
    "train_name": ["sbs local", "Shuttle Mak", "beast tar"],
    "zone_id": 3329
  }
  ],
  indices = data.reduce((p,c,i) => c.stop_name == "SAN FRANCISCO" && c.arrival_name == "SAN ANTONIO" ? p.concat(i):p,[]),
    index = data.findIndex(e => e.stop_name == "SAN FRANCISCO" && e.arrival_name == "SAN ANTONIO");
console.log(indices);
console.log(index);
```